# Actionscript3.0 - Why the value of Math.cos(35.26) is Minus?

Tags: actionscript-3, degrees, radians

```
trace(Math.cos(45));
//0.5253219888177297

trace(Math.cos(30));
//0.15425144988758405

trace(Math.cos(35.264));
//-0.7606511017750149
```

I'm confused. Do I need to lean Math at the Middle School?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you're passing degrees and `Math.cos()` wants radians:

```
trace(Math.cos(toRad(45)));
//0.7071067811865476

trace(Math.cos(toRad(30)));
//0.8660254037844387

trace(Math.cos(toRad(35.264)));
//0.8165005076106897

function toRad($deg:Number):Number 
{
    return ($deg/180)*Math.PI;
}
```

[Degree - Radian conversion](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Math.html)